# Image refresh not happening when base64 image string updated in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image

When I upload a new image I want the profile picture image to change to this new image without reloading the page or switch between the pages. I am using jQuery with the AJAX `get` method to change the source of the image to base64 encoded string.

display profile picture jQuery function -

```
$("img.profilepicture").each(function () {  
  var profileid = $("#profileid").val();
  var action = "image";
  var self = $(this);
  getprofileimage(profileid, action,self);
});

function getprofileimage(profileid,  action,  self) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "StoryServlet",
    data: {
      'action': action,
      'for': profileid,
      'timestamp': new Date().getTime()
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) {
      self.attr('src',data.base64String);
      self.attr('title','profilepic');
    }
  });     
}
```

Upload image jQuery function -

```
$("#uploadpic").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "StoryServlet",
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) {
      $("#picsucess").text(data.filename + " " + "uploaded sucessfully!");
      $("#picsucess").fadeIn();
      $("#picsucess").fadeOut(10000);
    }    
  }).done(function (data) {
     //done block
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    $("#fadein").text('File upload failed ...');
    $("#fadein").fadeIn();
    $("#fadein").fadeOut(10000);
  }).complete(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    location.reload();
  });       
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

You need to process the data passed to $.ajax in this case(display profile picture function) and also for it to set the content type for it to be properly read on the server.
Also add

```
 dataType: 'json',
```

to be safe. and make sure your response is valid json.

Comment: Removing processData: false, contentType: false, did the job. Thanks!